# Can a search engine receive DMCA takedowns? (linking to copyrighted content)

Tags: internet, canada, legal-research, dmca

I have a site similar to google.com based in canada that indexes various websites online. Some of these sites link directly or indirectly to copyrighted content. I have a "torrent" tab that lets you seek out such sites.

Is it illegal to link to such sites? Can someone send me a DMCA takedown for simply linking to sites like the pirate bay?

Comment: Clearly, [Google allows to send a "remove this from the search"](https://support.google.com/legal/troubleshooter/1114905?hl=en) in its forms.

Comment: @Trish very helpful. Thank you!!